# Get json from AWS S3 upload

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I am using [jQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in combination with [Tim Peterson's Amazon AWS S3 upload handler](https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/8172999) to upload files to S3. My goal is to get the filename stored by AWS. If I upload foo.mov ten times, S3 will name it foo.mov, foo(1).mov, foo(2).mov and so forth. After a successful upload, I get a response in the console of a JSON string from these methods:

```
protected function generate_response($content, $print_response = true) {
    if ($print_response) {
        $json = json_encode($content);
        $redirect = isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) ?
            stripslashes($_REQUEST['redirect']) : null;
        if ($redirect) {
            $this->header('Location: '.sprintf($redirect, rawurlencode($json)));
            return;
        }
        $this->head();
        if ($this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE')) {
            $files = isset($content[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
                $content[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
            if ($files && is_array($files) && is_object($files[0]) && $files[0]->size) {
                $this->header('Range: 0-'.(
                    $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($files[0]->size)) - 1
                ));
            }
        }
        $this->body($json);
    }
    return $content;
}



public function post($print_response = true) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['_method']) && $_REQUEST['_method'] === 'DELETE') {
        return $this->delete($print_response);
    }
    $upload = isset($_FILES[$this->options['param_name']]) ?
        $_FILES[$this->options['param_name']] : null;
    // Parse the Content-Disposition header, if available:
    $file_name = $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION') ?
        rawurldecode(preg_replace(
            '/(^[^"]+")|("$)/',
            '',
            $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_DISPOSITION')
        )) : null;
    // Parse the Content-Range header, which has the following form:
    // Content-Range: bytes 0-524287/2000000
    $content_range = $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE') ?
        preg_split('/[^0-9]+/', $this->get_server_var('HTTP_CONTENT_RANGE')) : null;
    $size =  $content_range ? $content_range[3] : null;
    $files = array();
    if ($upload && is_array($upload['tmp_name'])) {
        // param_name is an array identifier like "files[]",
        // $_FILES is a multi-dimensional array:
        foreach ($upload['tmp_name'] as $index => $value) {
            $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                $upload['tmp_name'][$index],
                $file_name ? $file_name : $upload['name'][$index],
                $size ? $size : $upload['size'][$index],
                $upload['type'][$index],
                $upload['error'][$index],
                $index,
                $content_range
            );
        }
    } else {
        if( isset($_POST['fileSourceChooser']) && $_POST['fileSourceChooser']=='dropbox' ){

            //http://justinvincent.com/page/1087/how-to-get-the-mime-type-of-a-remote-file-in-php-with-redirects
            function get_url_mime_type($url){
                $ch = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
                curl_exec($ch);
                return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
            }
                $upload=$_POST['files']; ////if just a regular post
                $upload['parse_url']=parse_url($upload['link']);
                $upload['url']='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com'.$upload['parse_url']['path'];
                    $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                        $upload['url'],
                        $file_name ? $file_name : $upload['name'],
                        $size ? $size : $upload['bytes'],
                        get_url_mime_type($upload['url']), 
                        "", 
                        null, null,
                        $content_range
                    );  

                    file_put_contents(
                        $this->options['upload_dir'].'thumbnail/'.$upload['name'],
                        fopen($upload['thumbnail'], 'r'),
                        FILE_APPEND //$append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
                    );                        
        }
        else{
            // param_name is a single object identifier like "file",
            // $_FILES is a one-dimensional array:
            $files[] = $this->handle_file_upload(
                isset($upload['tmp_name']) ? $upload['tmp_name'] : null,
                $file_name ? $file_name : (isset($upload['name']) ?
                        $upload['name'] : null),
                $size ? $size : (isset($upload['size']) ?
                        $upload['size'] : $this->get_server_var('CONTENT_LENGTH')),
                isset($upload['type']) ?
                        $upload['type'] : $this->get_server_var('CONTENT_TYPE'),
                isset($upload['error']) ? $upload['error'] : null,
                null,
                $content_range
            );                
        }
    }

    $AWSresponse = $this->generate_response(
        array($this->options['param_name'] => $files),
        $print_response
    );

    return $AWSresponse;
}
```

That response looks like this:

```
{"files":[{"name":"foo (51).mov","size":1202952,"type":"video\/quicktime","url":"https:\/\/me.s3.amazonaws.com\/bucket\/foo%20%2851%29.mov","deleteUrl":"https:\/\/myurl.com\/folder\/path\/?file=foo%20%2851%29.mov&_method=DELETE","deleteType":"POST"}]}
```

How can I go about accessing this information from outside of the UploadHandler class? I was thinking I could try setting a variable within the post method (named AWSresponse) which gets set to this value, but that did not work.

The class gets executed by this:

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this (this does not work):

```
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
$response = $upload_handler::$AWSresponse;
```

Comment: *If I upload foo.mov ten times, S3 will name it...* ... S3 doesn't name (or rename) anything.  The name of the object in S3 is whatever your code sends.

Comment: True. Unless the file name matches another in the bucket.

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  S3 does not have concept of behaving differently if the name matches another object.  The old object is simply overwritten in that case.  (The old version is not destroyed if bucket versioning is enabled, but it's only accessible by its opaque version identifier, and even then the name does not change.) If your files are getting different names, S3 is absolutely not doing that... whatever code you're using to upload the file must be doing that.

Comment: I stand corrected! I thought it was S3 - I missed the overwriting. But the second question still stands for getting the name out of the uploadhandler: how do I access the variable inside the class when it is showing an empty value via`$upload_handler::$AWSresponse` but if I echo the $AWSresponse variable in the method, it has contents?